# JS local and global scope variable and function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

The objective is to randomly select an image by making a variable "id" be a random number. The problem is how to use it on the function that makes somethings disappear and adds the random image and also use it in the "checkAnswer()" function.

Is this code right?

```
var cobras=new Array();

cobras[0] = '<img src="cobra1.jpg">';
cobras[1] = '<img src="cobra2.jpg">';
cobras[2] = '<img src="cobra3.jpg">';
cobras[3] = '<img src="cobra4.jpg">';
cobras[4] = '<img src="cobra5.jpg">';
cobras[5] = '<img src="cobra6.jpg">';
cobras[6] = '<img src="cobra7.jpg">';
cobras[7] = '<img src="cobra8.jpg">';
cobras[8] = '<img src="cobra9.jpg">';
cobras[9] = '<img src="cobra10.jpg">';
cobras[10] = '<img src="cobra11.jpg">';

id=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); 

function makeDisappear() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("main");
    elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var elem = document.getElementById("empty");
    elem.style.visibility = "visible";

    var bodyE1 = document.body;
    bodyE1.innerHTML += cobras[id];
}

function checkAnswer(a) {
    if (a==id) {
        alert('Correct!')
    }
    else {
        alert('Wrong!')
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling `checkAnswer`:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,230,190,40" alt="1" onclick="checkAnswer('1')">
```

Comment: Does your code work? Does it result in errors in the browser console?

Comment: It does add a new image with bodyE1.innerHTML += cobras[id], but the checkAnswer doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't shown how the "checkAnswer" function is called.

Comment: The elem with the "empty" id is an image that I've separated in different areas.

Comment: I don't think you'll ever select your first image. Your random part should read: `Math.floor(Math.random()*11)` (you have 11 images after all)

Comment: <area shape="rect" coords="0,230,190,40" alt="1" onclick="checkAnswer('1')"> If I change the id on the function code to a fix number it works

Comment: I haven't really payed a lot of attention to that part yet, it's actually 15 images.. but if random() returns a number between 0 and 1, I guess I only need to take the +1 out

Comment: Why are you passing a string into checkAnswer? It should technically work since you're using `==`, but it should probably be a number instead.

Comment: I though that Math.floor would return an number. There used to be another function, randomImage(), and the random part was inside it. But then I couldn't check the answer, because I didn't know which image was selected in the randomImage() scope

Comment: Right, it **is** a number, but `'1'` isn't. It's a string that represents a number. If you use `===` it will fail, but I think `==` will work since it does type conversion.

Comment: Oh got it, in the area code.. yeah it worked now, but the #10 area doesn't. If I click any other it alert either Correct! or Wrong!, except in the #10, nothing happens there. I tried to take the '+1' out and completed the 15 images. Still nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `window.id` instead of `id`?

I'm fairly sure that is a global variable.